# MIPS - Revision What does this program actually do?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

```
            .text
      main:  la    $a0, A #loads address of A into $a0
             li    $t0, 1 #loads 1 into $t0
             sw    $t0, ($a0) #stores word from $a0 into $t0
             li    $t0, 2 #loads 2 into $t0
             sw    $t0, 4($a0)
             li    $t0, 3
             sw    $t0, 8($a0)
             li    $t0, 4
             sw    $t0, 12($a0)

             la    $a1, A
             li    $v0, 1
             lw    $a0, ($a1)
             syscall
             lw    $a0, 4($a1)
             syscall
             lw    $a0, 8($a1)
             syscall
             lw    $a0, 12($a1)
             syscall
             la    $a0, tab
             li    $v0, 4
             syscall      
             li    $v0, 10
             syscall    

            .data
         A: .space 16 #array size 16
       tab: .asciiz "\t" #makes line indentation
#stores 1 - 4 into $t0
```

From what I can see, it loads the address of A into  a0, then it loads '1' into $t0, then it overrides?!? $t0, by storing the array into it., then loads 2 into $t0, then I'm unsure what the 4 is supposed to do(doesn't do anything as far as I can see, then loads $t0 into 3, then same as '4' don't don't see what 8 does, then loads 4 into $t0, then does something with 12, and then it loads address of A, into $a1, and prints it?!? I'm completely lost about the rest of the program. The program is correct,(loads "1234"), but I am supposed to learn MIPS, by understanding what each program the class lecturer gives. This isn't homework or anything,  just learning how MIPS programs work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program first stores the constants 1, 2, 3, 4 starting at the address of A, and then it just prints the contents of those four words.

Instruction `sw reg1, offset(reg2)` stores the contents of the register reg1 into the address pointed by reg2 plus the optional offset specified.

So, in your first example `sw $t0, ($a0)` will store the contents of $t0 in the address pointed by $a0, which in your case is the address of label A.

It then uses multiples of 4 as the offset because you are storing words and each word occupies exactly 4 bytes, therefore to store the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 at consecutive words you have to add 4 to each previous address.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an unrolled loop. The first loop sets the content of the array and the second loop prints out the contents of the array followed by a tab. Here's what I would assume the pseudo code would look like:

```
function main()
{
  i = 1
  while( i <= 4 )
  {
    A[i-1] = i
    i = i + 1
  }

  i = 1
  while( i <= 4 )
  {
    printToConsole( A[i-1] )
    i = i + 1
  }
  printToConsole( tab )
}
```

When the code was assembled, the assembler possibly unrolled the loop as a performance improvement.

Comment: @gusbro Thanks. I was confused by his inline comments, but fixed my example.